# How to work with time interval in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgreSQL query that returns 'Late' when the given condition is met, currently, When i run below query I'm getting an error

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CAST(so.scheduled_delivery_time AS date) < CURRENT_DATE OR CAST(so.scheduled_delivery_time AS date) = CURRENT_DATE AND DATETIME(so.scheduled_delivery_time) < DATETIME_SUB(datetime(current_datetime()),  INTERVAL '3' HOUR) THEN 'Late'
END AS status
FROM 
table1
```

**Error**

> ERROR: function datetime(timestamp without time zone) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hey there — the simplest answer is that there is no function named `DATETIME`. Also it looks like your values are already timestamps, so you can probably just do this:

`so.scheduled_delivery_time < current_datetime() - INTERVAL '3' HOUR`

Comment: I'm getting an error ``ERROR: function current_datetime() does not exist ``, any idea?

Comment: There is also no function `current_datetime()` in Postgres

Comment: Yes true, you can use CURRENT_DATE like you did above. Highly recommend the Postgres docs, they're pretty clear about stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point to find the available functions, is the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will give you the current timestamp and you can use it like this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```